# "Unwrapping" posted JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking for a way to "unwrap" JSON that's been posted to a MVC Core service. Let's say, I have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]        
public dynamic SayHello(string FirstName, string SecondName)
{
    return $"Hello {FirstName} {SecondName} !";
}
```

And I post in the following JSON:

```
{
    "FirstName":"Joe",
    "SecondName": "Bloggs"
}
```

I'd expect to get a response of `Hello Joe Bloggs !`, but I cannot seem to find an easy way to unwrap the JSON object into the properties of the method.

I know the correct solution is to have a `HelloModel` with those two properties in, slap on a `[FromBody]` attribute, but for reasons this isn't possible.

Comment: Why exactly can't you create a model here? Also, have you tried adding `[FromBody]` to the parameters?

Comment: @DavidG I cannot go into the reasons on a public forum. FromBody does not change outcome, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of the Chrome dev tools showing `Network -> Headers` for your **POST**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another (slightly convoluted) option. You can create your own action filter to intercept the request and populate the parameters with values based on deciding the JSON yourself. For example:

```
public class JsonToParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var stream = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var body = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(jsonTextReader);

            if (body == null) return;

            foreach (var parameter in filterContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters)
            {
                var jsonProperty = body.Properties().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter.Name);

                if (jsonProperty != null)
                {
                    var param = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.OfType<ControllerParameterDescriptor>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == parameter.Name);

                    if (param == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!filterContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(parameter.Name))
                    {
                        object value;

                        try
                        {
                            value = jsonProperty.Value.ToObject(param.ParameterInfo.ParameterType);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            value = GetDefault(param.ParameterInfo.ParameterType);
                        }

                        filterContext.ActionArguments.Add(parameter.Name, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static object GetDefault(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now decorate your action method with this new attribute:

```
[HttpPost]     
[JsonToParameters]   
public dynamic SayHello(string FirstName, string SecondName)
{
    return $"Hello {FirstName} {SecondName} !";
}
```

Comment: I had to slightly adapt your implementation - https://gist.github.com/surgicalcoder/0ea53d93a6fae663bbf8024f35408a51 - tested and works beautifully!

Comment: Haha I was just about to post an update because I noticed you were using .Net Core! Feel free to edit the answer and add your code if you like.